# Decomposing tensor powers of the fundamental representation of exceptional Lie algebras

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, young-tableaux, schur-functions

For the $A$-series, tensor powers of the fundamental representation of $\frak{sl}_n$ decompose into irreducibles according to a certain Young diagram/ partition formula. This inspires, for example, the theory of Schur functors.

What happens for the exceptional Lie algebras? For example, taking $V$, the fundamental representation of $E_6$, do we have a formula for the decomposition of its tensor powers? Is there a theory of "exceptional Schur functors"?

Comment: Probably there is no known answer.   Anyway, keep in mind that there are *six* fundamental modules for $E_6$ (the rank being 6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're e.g. looking for an analog of Schur-Weyl duality in other types, the combinatorics can get very tricky very quickly. For the symplectic group I believe the answer was first worked out by Sundaram in her PhD thesis (https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/15060) and meanwhile for the odd orthogonal group the answer was only obtained very recently by Jagenteufel (https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.03843).

Comment: These are useful references for certain classical types, but the question is about the *exceptional* types of simple Lie algebras.    Here there are limits to the knwn computational methods, but no analogue yet of Schur-Weyl theory.

Comment: @JimHumphreys: ah, I missed that the asker was interested specifically in exceptional types. (Though I'd then maybe point out that "fundamental representation" could be misleading... probably for $E_6$ you'd want one of the two isomorphic minuscule representations?)

Comment: @ Jim, Sam Thanks for the comments. Is there a reason why this problem has proved so difficult?

Comment: I think partially the reason is because the answer itself is complicated, at least compared to the simplicity of Schur-Weyl duality.